# zingchart scale-y-n zoomtovalue

Tags: scale, zooming, zingchart

It is possible to use the zoomtovalues in scale-y-2 ?
I have several series in multiple y-axis and I would like to zomm each scale-y-n to specific values, but I do not know how...

Thanks and regards,

Comment: Hi Bill, I'm on the ZingChart team. I don't see a way to do this in our source, although I may be able to implement this into our code by adding an additional option to the zoomtovalues method to allow for zooming on specific scales. Stay tuned!

Comment: Thank yhou Stalfos, I will be watching for the new updates :)

Answer (score 3):

We've added the ability to do this in one of our recent updates. To zoom in on a different scale, append the scale number onto the option in the zoomtovalues method call. E.G.:

```
zingchart.exec('myChart','zoomtovalues',{
  'ymin-2':0,
  'ymax-2':500000
});
```

This will zoom to 0, 500000 on scale-y-2 and can be seen in action [here](http://demos.zingchart.com/view/85SS78TL).

Sorry for the late answer... make sure to let me know if you have any other, newer questions!

Comment: Good to hear that, I will try the new method call :), Thanks Stalfos